# Send Ajax request from JqGrid ShowLink click

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I need to load some dynamic html when a user click on a link in a jqGrid.

here is my definition

```
function loadUserAdministrationList() {
    jQuery("#userlist").jqGrid({
        url: '/Administration/GetData/',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: ['Username', 'Prénom', 'Nom', 'Courriel'],
        colModel: [{ name: 'Username', index: 'Username', width: 300, align: 'left',
                     edittype: 'select', formatter: 'showlink',
                     formatoptions: { baseLinkUrl: '/Administration/ModifyUser'} },
              { name: 'Prénom', index: 'Firstname', width: 300, align: 'left' },
              { name: 'Nom', index: 'Lastname', width: 300, align: 'left' },
              { name: 'Courriel', index: 'Email', width: 300, align: 'left'}],
        pager: jQuery('#userlistpager'),
        rowNum: 20,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
        sortname: 'Firstname',
        sortorder: "asc",
        height:600,
        viewrecords: true,
        imgpath: '/Public/css/theme/custom/images',
        caption: '',
        loadtext: 'Chargement des utilisateurs...'
    }).navGrid('#userlistpager',
                { search: true, edit: false, add: false, del: false },
                {}, // default settings for edit
                {}, // default settings for add
                {}, // default settings for delete
                { closeOnEscape: true, multipleSearch: true,
                  closeAfterSearch: true }, //search options
                {}
    );
};
```

as you can see i would like to load a modification form.
How can i tell jqGrid to do an ajax call on the click of showLink ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution could looks like following:

1. In the 'Username' you remove unneeded `edittype: 'select'` and `align: 'left'` and consider to add `title: false` instead to remove displaying of the ToolTip on hover a cell with the mouse.
2. Modify `formatoptions` which contain `formatter: 'showlink'` to following: `formatoptions: { baseLinkUrl: 'javascript:', showAction: "MyBase.GetAndShowUserData(jQuery('#userlist'),'#myDiv','", addParam: "');" }`. jqGrid will construct `href` attribute of `<a>` element like following: `href="javascript:MyBase.GetAndShowUserData(jQuery('#userlist'),'#userDetails','?id=rowId');"` where `rowId` will be the id of the corresponding grid row.
3. Add a **global** function (defined on the top level of your JavaScript) for example with the name `MyBase.GetAndShowUserData` like following:

(In the code below we use global `MyBase` only for namespacing)

```
var MyBase = {};
MyBase.GetAndShowUserData = function (grid,tagetDivSelector,param) {
    // param will be in the form '?id=rowId'. We need to get rowId
    var ar = param.split('=');
    if (grid.length > 0 && ar.length === 2 && ar[0] === '?id') {
        var rowid = ar[1];
        var username = grid.getCell(rowid, 'Username');
        var userDetails = jQuery(tagetDivSelector);
        userDetails.empty();
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '/Administration/ModifyUser',
            data: { userId: rowid, userName: username },
            type: 'GET',
            // optional contentType (depend on your server environment):
            // contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(data,st) {
                var s = "BlaBla";
                // TODO: construct HTML code based on data received from the server
                userDetails.html(s);
            },
            error:function(xhr,st,err){
                alert(st + ": " + data.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

I suppose here, that on your page there are a `<div>` or other element with `id="userDetails"` like

```
<table id="userlist"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
<div id="userDetails"></div>
```

and the function `MyBase.GetAndShowUserData` will make an ajax call and fill the results inside the `<div id="userDetails"></div>`. The code inside of `MyBase.GetAndShowUserData` is a raw template only. I wanted only to show how you can access the data from the grid.