# jqgrid showLink

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using showlink formatter to make a column as a link. is there a way I can call a javascript function when I click on that.

Right now this is the code I have

```
$("#list").jqGrid(  

{
     url: '..',
    datatype: 'json', //We specify that the datatype we will be using will be JSON
    colNames:['ID', 'User Name'],      
                colModel :[
     {name:'id',index:'id', width:110, sorttype:"string", formatter: 'showlink', formatoptions:{baseLinkUrl:'index.cfm'}},
```

...

I dont want to use the baselinkUrl. Instead can I call a Javascript function on clicking the URL? Also my form data does not seem to get posted to the next screen when I am using the 'showlink' formatter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this in different ways. The first one is to use `formatter:'showlink'` in the form like the following

```
formatoptions: {
    baseLinkUrl: 'javascript:',
    showAction: "MyBase.GetAndShowUserData(jQuery('#list'),'",
    addParam: "');"
}
```

(see my [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605197/send-ajax-request-from-jqgrid-showlink-click/3608421#3608421) for details). It will produce the `<a>` link with

```
href="javascript:MyBase.GetAndShowUserData(jQuery('#userlist'),'?id=rowId');"
```

where `rowId` will be the id of the corresponding grid row. Inside of your custom **global** function `MyBase.GetAndShowUserData` you should cut `"?id="` prefix from the second parameter. So you will be able to access the grid and you will know the selected id.

One more way is to write you own [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) instead of the usage of `formatter:'showlink'`.

The main disadvantage of both approaches in my opinion is the usage of **global** functions. Moreover I prefer to follow concept of [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). So I can suggest you another way from [my answer](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/format-link-for-url-rewriting/#p21162) on the trirand forum. The idea is to use predefined formatter `showlink` with '#' as the value of `href` attribute and **to make binding** to the `click` event of the link inside of `loadComplete` function:

```
colModel: [
    { name: 'Subcategory', formatter:'showlink',formatoptions:{baseLinkUrl:'#'}
...
loadComplete: function() {
    var myGrid = $("#list");
    var ids = myGrid.getDataIDs();
    for (var i = 0, idCount = ids.length; i < idCount; i++) {
        $("#"+ids[i]+" a",myGrid[0]).click(function(e) {
            var hash=e.currentTarget.hash;// string like "#?id=0"
            if (hash.substring(0,5) === '#?id=') {
                var id = hash.substring(5,hash.length);
                var text = this.textContent || this.innerText;
                alert("clicked the row with id='"+id+"'. Link contain '"+text+"'");
                location.href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"+text;
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    }   
}
```

see live demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/UnobtrusiveLinks.htm). In the demo if you click on the text like "Physics" in the table it will be opened the url http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physics which will be build dynamical. I included an additional alert to show how to decode information about the row id additionally.

**UPDATED:** Look at the improved code (from the performance side) of `loadComplete` in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010761/linking-from-a-column-value-in-jqgrid-to-a-new-page-using-get/5017528#5017528).

Comment: Thanks a lot Oleg. That works. Is there anything related to what you told in the jggrid documentation page?

Comment: @user508518: You welcome! The place in jqgrid documentation where `showlink` is described: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter#predefined_format_types (see also example on the same page).

Comment: @Oleg, I have a question if I have two columns with hyperlinks, and want a different outcome for each, is that possible?

Comment: @user508518: Yes, it is possible. For example, you can use different `addParam` values in the columns. The values will be appended to the URL after `?id=rowId`, so is you will use in one column `&col=foo` and for another `&col=foo` then you will have the corresponding text appended to `?id=rowId`. Just start `addParam` values with a charachters which can ba a good separator, so you can easy cut off the information inside of your `click` event handler.

Comment: @Oleg. I have some complicated scenario here. I have three columns from my database query. They are userid, username, and email. I want to display only userid and username, and both of them have hyperlinks. From your solution above, i got the link for userid to be customized how I want. For username also I want a link, but with the link should open up my email client, with the email value for that row from the database. All this seems a bit complicated with jqgrid.

Comment: @user508518: It seems to me easy to implement what you need. Just the `showlink` formatter is not flexible enough. Inside of `click` handler you will know the row id which are clicked (see my answer above). So you can get the contain of any cell of the row with respect of `getCell` method (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) or with respect of `getRowData` method. In case of local editing (or in case of `loadonce:true`) you can use also `jqGrid('getGridParam','data')` to get all reference to local data from all pages at once.

Comment: @Oleg. Thanks for replying. How can I get the row id? In the above code, in the click function, oyu passed a parameter e. I got the solution by using addParams, but how to get the rowid value and associated columns value

Comment: @user508518: `var id = hash.substring(5,hash.length);` is the row id, so you can use it as a parameter of `getRowData` or `getCell`: `myGrid.jqGrid('getRowData',id)` or `myGrid.jqGrid('getCell',id,'email')`

Comment: @Oleg. Thanks a lot. I learnt a lot from you. Can you also let me know if there is a way to know the IDs of the elements created by jqGrid. For example, for creating a bottom pager, we mention it <div id="pager">, but when I say 'clonetotop:true', jqgrid clones the pager and automatically assigns an id of 'list_toppager'. How can I view this information?

Comment: @user508518: If you use `toppager:true` and 'cloneToTop:true' parameter of `navGrid` method, another my old answer with including small demo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552855/add-toolbar-in-the-bottom-of-the-header-using-jqgrid/3557663#3557663 could be interesting for you. The answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683108/jqgrid-footer-cells-inherits-css-from-cells-in-the-main-grid/2697747#2697747 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462071/jqgrid-get-th-and-thead-using-jquery/3463002#3463002 describes ids and classes of the most important divs of jqGrid.

Comment: @user508518: By the way you can use vote up answers or questions which was helpful for you (see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/).

Comment: @Oleg. Looks like I need to have atleast 15 reputation to do that.

Comment: @user508518: Sorry, I don't known it. The reputation system have too many different roles. By the way in another recent answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402455/unable-to-position-pager-navigation-bar-above-jqgrid I explained a little about pagers which you asked me before.

Comment: @Oleg: It helped me put a hyperlink and call to a javascript function `{name:'cfgName',index:'cfgName', width:90, align:"right", formatter: 'showlink', formatoptions:
                         {
                          baseLinkUrl:'javascript:',
                          showAction: "goToViewAllPage('",
                             addParam: "');"
                            
                         }},`

Comment: @Oleg: can you see 2 more questions in jqGrid for me? I am posting them right now :)