# How to get Data Row Selected in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, jqgrid-formatter

i'm starter in jqGrid, i have 2 jqGrid in the page , in the Grid1 i have inCustom and OutCustom i want user click in Grid get Data inCustom and outCustom in write this code

```
var grid = $('#list');
grid.jqGrid({
    url: 'jQGridHandler.ashx',
    postData: { ActionPage: 'ClearanceRequest', Action: 'Fill' },
    ajaxGridOptions: { cache: false },
    loadonce: true,
    direction: "rtl",
    datatype: 'json',
    height: 600,
    width: 1000,
    colNames: ['', '', '', ' ', '', '', '', '', '',
               '', '', ' ', '', '', '', '', '', '',
               '', ' ', '', '', '', '',
               '', '', '', '', '', '', ' ',
               '', '', '', '', '', ''],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'REQUEST_ID', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
        { name: 'REQUEST_DATE', width: 50, sortable: true },
        { name: 'REQUEST_NO', width: 60, sortable: true },
        { name: 'CUSTOMER_ID', width: 100, sortable: true },
        { name: 'TRANSPORT_TYPE', width: 40, sortable: true },
        { name: 'CLEARANCE_TYPE', width: 50, sortable: true },
        { name: 'IMPORT_EXPORT', width: 30, sortable: true, editable: false,
            edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: { value: "True:False" },
            formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: { disabled: false }, hidden: true
        },
        { name: 'WAYBILL_NO', width: 50, sortable: true },
        { name: 'WAYBILL_OFFICE', width: 100, sortable: true },
        { name: 'MANIFEST', width: 200, sortable: true, hidden: true },
        { name: 'STORE_BILL', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
        { name: 'DIRECT_NO', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
        { name: 'STORE_DATE', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
        { name: 'INOUT_DATE', width: 50, sortable: true, hidden: true },
        { name: 'SOURCE_COUNTRY', width: 30, sortable: true, hidden: true },
        { name: 'SOURCE_CITY', width: 80, sortable: true, hidden: true },
        { name: 'DESTINATION_COUNTRY', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
        { name: 'IN_CUSTOMS', width: 200, sortable: true, hidden: true },
        { name: 'OUT_CUSTOMS', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
        { name: 'INSURER_ID', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
        { name: 'INSURANCE_NO', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
        { name: 'CLEARANCE_PERSON', width: 50, sortable: true, hidden: true },
        { name: 'PROXY_NO', width: 30, sortable: true, hidden: true },
        { name: 'FACTOR_NO', width: 80, sortable: true, hidden: true },
        { name: 'SHIP_NAME', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
        { name: 'TRAVEL_NO', width: 200, sortable: true, hidden: true },
        { name: 'INDENT_NO', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
        { name: 'COOTAG_NO', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
        { name: 'PERMIT_NO', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
        { name: 'CLEARANCE_NO', width: 50, sortable: true, hidden: true },
        { name: 'CARNETIR_NO', width: 30, sortable: true, hidden: true },
        { name: 'PURCHASE_TYPE', width: 80, sortable: true, hidden: true },
        { name: 'ALL_VALUE', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
        { name: 'FREIGHT_STATUS', width: 30, sortable: true, editable: false,
            edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: { value: "True:False" },
            formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: { disabled: false }, hidden: true
        },
        { name: 'COPY_ORIGINAL', width: 30, sortable: true, editable: false,
            edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: { value: "True:False" },
            formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: { disabled: false }, hidden: true
        },
        { name: 'REMARK', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
        { name: 'details', width: 20, sortable: false, search: false,
            formatter: function () {
                return "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-document'></span>";
            }
        }
    ],
    gridview: true,
    rowNum: 30,
    rowList: [30, 60, 90],
    pager: '#pager',
    sortname: 'WorkOrderNo',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: 'ASC',
    rownumbers: true,
    beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
        var iCol = $.jgrid.getCellIndex(e.target);
        // alert(rowid);
        console.log(rowid);
        //listItem
        console.log($.jgrid.getCellIndex(e.target));
        if ($.jgrid.getCellIndex(e.target) == 37) {
            $("#listItem").jqGrid("GridUnload");
            var gridItem = $('#listItem');
            gridItem.jqGrid({
                url: 'jQGridHandler.ashx',
                postData: { ActionPage: 'ClearanceItems', Action: 'Fill', requestId: rowid },
                ajaxGridOptions: { cache: false },
                loadonce: true,
                direction: "rtl",
                datatype: 'json',
                height: 200,
                colNames: ['', '', '', '', ' ', ' ', '',
                           '', '', 'ا', ' ', '', ' ',
                           '', '', ' ', '  ',
                           '', '', '', ' ', '  ', ' ', ' ', ''],
                colModel: [
                    { name: 'REQUEST_ID', width: 100, sortable: true },
                    { name: 'ITEM_NO', width: 200, sortable: true },
                    { name: 'GOODS_DESCRIPTION', width: 100, sortable: true },
                    { name: 'QUANTITY', width: 100, sortable: true },
                    { name: 'PACKING_TYPE', width: 100, sortable: true },
                    { name: 'GROSS_WEIGHT', width: 50, sortable: true },
                    { name: 'TARE_WEIGHT', width: 30, sortable: true },
                    { name: 'MEASUREMENT_TYPE', width: 80, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                    { name: 'GOODS_PRICE', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                    { name: 'GOODS_CURRENCY', width: 200, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                    { name: 'GOODS_CURRENCY_RATE', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                    { name: 'FREIGHT_PRICE', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                    { name: 'FREIGHT_CURRENCY', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                    { name: 'FREIGHT_CURRENCY_RATE', width: 50, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                    { name: 'INSURANCE_PRICE', width: 30, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                    { name: 'INSURANCE_CURRENCY', width: 80, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                    { name: 'INSURANCE_CURRENCY_RATE', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                    { name: 'TARIFF_NO', width: 200, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                    { name: 'CUSTOM_PRICE', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                    { name: 'WARRANTY_PRICE', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                    { name: 'INOUT_DATE', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                    { name: 'VEHICLE_TYPE', width: 50, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                    { name: 'VEHICLE_NO', width: 30, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                    { name: 'WAREHOUSE_ID', width: 80, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                    { name: 'REMARK', width: 80, sortable: true, hidden: true }
                ],
                gridview: true,
                rowNum: 20,
                rowList: [20, 40, 60],
                pager: '#pagerItem',
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: 'ASC',
                rownumbers: true
            });
            gridItem.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pagerItem', { add: true, edit: true, del: true },
                {}, {}, {}, { multipleSearch: true, overlay: false, width: 460 });

            var myGrid = grid;
            var selRowId = myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
            celValue = myGrid.jqGrid('getCell', selRowId, 'IN_CUSTOMS');
            celValue2 = myGrid.jqGrid('getCell', selRowId, 'OUT_CUSTOMS');

            console.log(celValue);

            console.log(celValue2);

            alert(celValue);
            alert(celValue2);

            $("#POPUP2").dialog({ width: 780 });
        }

        return true;
    }
});
grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { add: false, edit: false, del: true },
    {}, {}, {}, { multipleSearch: true, overlay: false, width: 460 })
         .navButtonAdd("#pager", {
             caption: "",
             buttonicon: "ui-icon-plus",
             onClickButton: function () {
                 // alert("Adding Row");
                 $("#POPUP1").dialog({ width: 730 });
             },
             position: "first"

         })
         .navButtonAdd("#pager", {
             caption: "",
             buttonicon: "ui-icon ui-icon-pencil",
             onClickButton: function () {

             },
             position: "first"

         })
          .navButtonAdd("#pager", {
              caption: "",
              buttonicon: "ui-icon ui-icon-trash",
              onClickButton: function () {

              },
              position: "first"
          });
```

When first click in detils button get false value but after then return correct data
[image]

thanks all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all I answer on your main question. The problem is that you get `selrow` parameter (the id of selected row) inside of `beforeSelectRow` callback. At the first click on 'details' button no row is selected. So `myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow')` will return `null` and you will be unable to use `getCell` to get values from `'IN_CUSTOMS'` and `'OUT_CUSTOMS'` column of the row with id=null.

You always return true from `beforeSelectRow` callback. So you don't want to prevent row selection if the user click on the 'details' button. In the case I would recommend you better to use [onCellSelect](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_events) callback. By the way the callback has `iCol` (the index of the cell which was clicked) as additional parameter. It will additional simplify your code.

Next remark. You use `sortable: true` in all column, but the default value of `sortable` property is already `true` (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options)). Additional I would recommend you to use [column templates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6047856/315935) in the definition of jqGrid. For example in the definition of the first grid you use multiple times the same properties to define hidden column with the checkbox. Additionally there are many columns having `width: 100` and all columns have empty column header `''`. So you can define the first grid as

```
var grid = $('#list'),
    hiddenCheckboxTemplate = { width: 30, editable: false,
        edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: { value: "True:False" },
        formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: { disabled: false }, hidden: true
    };
grid.jqGrid({
    colModel: [
        { name: 'REQUEST_ID', hidden: true },
        { name: 'REQUEST_DATE', width: 50 },
        { name: 'REQUEST_NO', width: 60 },
        { name: 'CUSTOMER_ID' },
        { name: 'TRANSPORT_TYPE', width: 40 },
        { name: 'CLEARANCE_TYPE', width: 50 },
        { name: 'IMPORT_EXPORT', template: hiddenCheckboxTemplate },
        { name: 'WAYBILL_NO', width: 50 },
        { name: 'WAYBILL_OFFICE' },
        { name: 'MANIFEST', width: 200, hidden: true },
        { name: 'STORE_BILL', hidden: true },
        { name: 'DIRECT_NO', hidden: true },
        { name: 'STORE_DATE', hidden: true },
        { name: 'INOUT_DATE', width: 50, hidden: true },
        { name: 'SOURCE_COUNTRY', width: 30, hidden: true },
        { name: 'SOURCE_CITY', width: 80, hidden: true },
        { name: 'DESTINATION_COUNTRY', hidden: true },
        { name: 'IN_CUSTOMS', width: 200, hidden: true },
        { name: 'OUT_CUSTOMS', hidden: true },
        { name: 'INSURER_ID', hidden: true },
        { name: 'INSURANCE_NO', hidden: true },
        { name: 'CLEARANCE_PERSON', width: 50, hidden: true },
        { name: 'PROXY_NO', width: 30, hidden: true },
        { name: 'FACTOR_NO', width: 80, hidden: true },
        { name: 'SHIP_NAME', hidden: true },
        { name: 'TRAVEL_NO', width: 200, hidden: true },
        { name: 'INDENT_NO', hidden: true },
        { name: 'COOTAG_NO', hidden: true },
        { name: 'PERMIT_NO', hidden: true },
        { name: 'CLEARANCE_NO', width: 50, hidden: true },
        { name: 'CARNETIR_NO', width: 30, hidden: true },
        { name: 'PURCHASE_TYPE', width: 80, hidden: true },
        { name: 'ALL_VALUE', hidden: true },
        { name: 'FREIGHT_STATUS', template: hiddenCheckboxTemplate },
        { name: 'COPY_ORIGINAL', template: hiddenCheckboxTemplate },
        { name: 'REMARK', hidden: true },
        { name: 'details', width: 20, sortable: false, search: false,
            formatter: function () {
                return "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-document'></span>";
            }
        }
    ],
    cmTemplate: { width: 100, label: '' },
    ... other option. No colNames are needed because of usage label
});
```

In the way you reduce the code and make it more manageable (easy to maintain). Because of usage `label` property in `colModel` no `colNames` option should be included.

In the same way you can reduce the code which define the second grid too.

Another remark. the code `if ($.jgrid.getCellIndex(e.target) == 37) {` is difficult to understand and to maintain. If you would include additional column in the grid or if you even change the value of some option (like `rownumbers`) the constant `37` should be changed. What you want to do is just test whether the user clicked on the 'details' column. I would recommend you to use better the column names. For example

```
var colModel = $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel'),
    cm = colModel[iCol]; // iCol is defined before as $.jgrid.getCellIndex(e.target)
if (cm && cm.name === 'details') {
    ....
}
```

The last remark. You use `GridUnload` and then **recreate** the second grid with details. It would be more effective to use `.trigger('reloadGrid', [{page: 1}])` instead (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3808014/315935)). At the beginning you can create the second grid with `datatype: 'local'`. It will prevent the loading of data from the server. You can place the second grid in div which you hide directly after the grid is created and show the div if needed. If the second grid need be filled with information you can use `setGridParam` to change `datatype` to 'json' (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4525139/315935)), set other parameters like `requestId` of `postData` and then call `.trigger('reloadGrid', [{page: 1}])`. The way will work more effectively.

Comment: @ Oleg: thanks for help me, i trace code and first when user click in details coulmn selRowId value is null but i select row but in second time in user clicked selRowId  get Correct data , just in first time return inCorrect data. please help me. thanks.

Comment: @MohsenBahrzadeh: In the first sentence of my answer I wrote that it's because you use `beforeSelectRow` callback which will be called **before** the row is selected. The most simple way to fix this the problem is to use `onSelectRow: function (id, state, e) {...}` instead of `beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {...}`