# Issue with jqGrid and jquery click event

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I'm loading a jqGrid on my page. The grid has a Delete button for each row. I'm trying to use the jquery UI dialog confirmation on my Delete button.

Here's my javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#list").jqGrid({
            url: '/MyController/MyFunction/',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'POST',
            colNames: ['', 'Name', ''],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'Edit', index: 'Edit', width: 40, align: 'left', sortable: false },
                { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 120, align: 'left' },
                { name: 'Delete', index: 'Delete', width: 50, align: 'left', sortable: false }],
            pager: $('#pager'),
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 50],
            sortname: 'Name',
            sortorder: "asc",
            viewrecords: true,
            width: 700
        });


        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Delete": function () {
                    window.location.href = $(this).attr("href"); ;
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });


        $("a.confirm").click(function () {
            alert("HELLO");
            //$("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
        });

    }); 

</script>
```

I'm passing in data from my controller to the grid. I have the class "confirm" added to the Delete link for each row.

If I click on my Delete button, nothing happens. The link has the correct class, and all my javascript is loading correctly. I placed an alert at the end of my document.ready function to make sure there were no errors.

But if I comment out my jqGrid and add a link onto my page with the class "confirm", the click event will fire.

Has anyone ever run into this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main problem which you have is that you try to make 'click' binding with `$("a.confirm").click(...)` **before** the elements "a.confirm" are loaded.

You should either place the binding code inside of [loadComplete](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events) or [gridComplete](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events) event handler or use [jQuery.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
$("a.confirm").live('click', function() {
    alert("HELLO");
    //$("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
});
```

instead of `$("a.confirm").click(...)`.

One more general remark. The best practice working with jqGrid is dividing data from the HTML markup. I suppose that you place HTML fragment with `<a class="confirm">...</a>` inside of JSON data returned from the server. jqGrid supports another ways to archive the same results. You can 1) use [showlink](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter) formatter; 2) use [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) which allow create any HTML fragment for the grid cell based on the row of data (see `rowObject` parameter) returned from the server 3) use unobtrusive JavaScript (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390999/jqgrid-showlink/4391786#4391786) with [the code example](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/UnobtrusiveLinks.htm)) 4) any mix from both (see [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497252/jqgrid-button-in-master-grid-each-row-to-load-detail-grid/4519333#4519333) with the code example). The way 3 seems me mostly close to what you do.

In any way having clear separation of JSON data from HTML markup is good not only because of design reason. It allows additionally reduce the size of data send from server. (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261687/best-way-to-create-a-link-using-jquery/4266076#4266076) for more information)

Comment: @volocuga: You are welcome! The answer is relatively old. Currently I will recommend to use custom formatter and `beforeSelectRow` or `onCellSelect` instead of any additional binding of `click` event handler. See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14537512/315935), [another one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13765086/315935) for code examples. [The old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5305904/315935) was the first for me when I saw the advantages on usage one common event handler to handle `click` event of multiple elements inside of grid.