# How make check box in the jqgrid uncheckable

Tags: jqgrid

I need to make a check-box uncheckable in JqGrid.
I have made a custom formatter to call a function for onClick event of the checkobx.

```
return "<input type=\"checkbox\" " + bchk +" onClick=\"clickMe\" " + " value=\""+
       cval+"\" offval=\"no\" "+ds+ "/>";
```

This function gets called fine.
Now I don't know how to stop the user from checking the unchecked check-box.
What I am trying to say is the user should be able to un-check but should be able to check again.

Thanks,
Abhi

Comment: return "<input type=\"checkbox\" " + bchk +" onClick=\"clickMe\" "  + " value=\""+ cval+"\" offval=\"no\" "+ds+ "/>";

Comment: If the checkbox can be used by user, the changes will be not saved in the grid automatically. How you plan to read new changed checkbox states?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to make [unobtrusive style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) binding to the onClick event (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010761/linking-from-a-column-value-in-jqgrid-to-a-new-page-using-get/5017528#5017528) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390999/jqgrid-showlink/4391786#4391786) answers for details. Inside of event handle you can use [e.preventDefault();](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to prevent default behavior of the chechbox click.

Comment: Thx for your reply Oleg,but I figured it out. I added the following code  loadComplete : function(){
           jQuery(".jqgrow td input").each(function(){
                  jQuery(this).click(function(){
                      $(this).attr('checked', false);

                  });
              });
          }