# Pop up a custom form with custom data on click of a cell in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I have a grid control displaying data about a Company. I want one column to be "Employee". On click on the any cell of "Employee" column I want to pop up the one Form called "Employee Details" and would like to feel the data.

How can I do this?

As I understand the modal form on click of a jqgrid cell deals with data only related to that row. I want to show different data on the pop up form, i.e. other than the grid data.

Pl help.

Shivali

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use [unobtrusive links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) in the column (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390999/jqgrid-showlink/4391786#4391786) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010761/linking-from-a-column-value-in-jqgrid-to-a-new-page-using-get/5017528#5017528) answers). The advantage of this technique is that instead of typical links you can define any custom action on click on the link. The look of the link can be defined by CSS, but it seems to the that the link can show the user better as other HTML elements, that the user can click on it.

Alternative you can use a button in the column with respect of the custom formatter, but with the same technique as described before you can free define which action will be done on the click.

Inside of the click event with the parameter 'e' you have `e.currentTarget` as the DOM element of `<a>` for the link or `<input>` or `<button>` if you use buttons in the grid column. To find the row id you can use `var row = $(e.currentTarget).closest("tr.jqgrow")` or `var row = $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow")` to find the `<tr>` element. The row id will be `row[0].id`.