# JQGRID: Pop Out view form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have column called notes this is used for tracking historical information .
I have placed a button and clicking it should show a form(Similar to View form) and display the information for that Row.The Data for this is stored in a different table.

The Form Should be

#### S.No.  Date                       User                Changes

1         01.02.2013          John                   Added Row
2         10.02.2013          John                   Updated Column Details
3         10.12.2013          Pravish       Updated Column Details

.... so on

I have got it working until I get the Row id using the solutions given by @Oleg
[Pop up a custom form with custom data on click of a cell in jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182007/pop-up-a-custom-form-with-custom-data-on-click-of-a-cell-in-jqgrid)

Can someone please help on this.

Thanks for your time

Regards,
Pravish

Comment: @Oleg Can you please help on this stackoverflow.com/questions/20193976/jqgrid-pop-out-view-form –  Pravish Jayasundar

Comment: Why don't you prepare a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/) ?