# jqgrid get record info with hyperlink

Tags: jqgrid

I have a table that has the following data in a grid:

```
ID   Course
2    Math
5    English
7    Science
9    History
12   Gym
```

What I like is for the value of ID and Course to be hyperlinks so they are clickable. When the user clicks on a given ID, I like to have an alert for that shows the given ID. When the user clicks on the Course, I like to have an alert
that shows both the ID and Course.

I am not sure how to do this. I understand there is a 
        showlink

but not sure how to tie it everything together.

Looking at a stackoverflow question, I can do the following:

```
    var grid = jQuery('#list');
    var sel_id = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
    var myCellData = grid.jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, 'MyColName');
```

where MyColName would be the name of the column but not sure how to tie it altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve the problem in many ways. The formatter `"showlink"` is oriented to create the standard HTML link `<a>` instead of usage JavaScript `click` event handler. You can do use formatter `"showlink"` (see my very [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4391786/315935)) to call your custom JavaScript code, but there are better ways for implementation. For example you can use [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) or to use `formatter: "dynamicLink"` which you can find [here](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid-plugins/blob/master/jQuery.jqGrid.dynamicLink.js) and which I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9048483/315935).

The best and the most easy way which I would suggest you now is the usage of **pseudo links**. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13765086/315935) or [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14537512/315935) for details.