# JQGrid Redirecting to aspx file on click on a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I am new to JQGrid and my objective is to redirect to a different page when user clicks on a hyperlink column cell in a jqgrid row. The content present inside this column would be common for each row. My colModel is as mentioned below

```
 { name: 'Edit', index: 'Edit', width: 130, align: "center", formatter: 'showlink', editable: true, resizable: true, formatoptions: { baseLinkUrl: 'EditUserDetails.aspx'} }
```

Now when i click on hyperlink, it is correctly redirecting to the specified page and by default in QueryString i get the rowid of the selected row but i want the value present in one of the columns for e.g. if I have two columns in my grid named UsedId and Edit, then on click of link, I should get the value of UserId present in the selected row in the QueryString. Can You Please guide me how to achieve this using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation at 
http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter

you will see you can include a `idName` parameter in your `formatoptions:` which would correspond to the row data you want to include which should solve your problem.

Another example is linked below of a similar question:

[JqGrid need hyperlink - need to capture value through Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529358/jqgrid-need-hyperlink-need-to-capture-value-through-jquery/14537512#14537512)

Comment: Thanks for replying but the idName parameter just gives the rowid of the selected, that anyways i was by default getting. The http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390999/jqgrid-showlink link solved my query

Comment: @RohitAgrawal Did you specify a different column name with the `idName` parameter or use the `addParam` parameter?

Comment: Yes Mark I had specified idName='UserId', but still I was getting the rowId of the grid.