# How to use jqGrid Custom Formatter and 'showlink' at the same time? Links in column do not appear link-like

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, jqgrid

I am trying to link the variables in the first column of my jqgrid to another page. Right now, the variables do not appear link-like OR exclusive (meaning no matter where I click on the row, I am taken to the destination page).

I need to use the custom formatter because the URL in my search bar should not change (I am running this on my local server). But with the custom formatter, I cannot seem to also use 'showlink' (which ultimately seems to make my data appear link-like when I'm not using the custom formatter). I want the finger cursor when hovering over the data in my first column, all I'm getting right now is the "I".

Is there someway I can use both
**formatter:'showlink'** from the predefined formatter AND **formatter: returnHyperLink(name)** from the custom formatter?  I want to be able to ONLY click the first column's data to be taken to the page, and I want this data to appear link-like ( should not be able to click anywhere on the row).

My relevant jqgrid code is:

```
    colNames:['Name','Status', 'Created On', 'Update By', 'Updated On', 'RetentionDays','ValidityTime','Edit'],
    colModel:[
              {  
                  name: 'name', width:100,editable: true, edittype:'select',
                  formatter: returnHyperLink(name),

                  xmlmap: function (obj) {
                      return $(obj).attr('name'); 
                  }

              },
```

And my function, **returnHyperLink** appears as:

function returnHyperLink(name){

```
$(this).click(function() {
      $( "#contents" ).load("jsp/consumers.jsp");
         console.log(this, "Hello world");

    });
```

};

...okay obviously something is wrong if all of this code isn't even showing up in the code box. I was thinking I could call the javascript function from inside of an href, but I also do not know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you misunderstand how the custom formatter works. jqGrid creates *the whole body of the grid (`<tbody>`) as the string*. Thus the custom formatter should return the string and no `$(this).click` inside of the formatter do not what you expect. The `<td>` element *not yet exist* during the custom formatter is working.

You don't wrote, which version of jqGrid and from which fork of jqGrid you use. If you would use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), then you can use `onClick` callback option of `formatter: "showlink"`:

```
formatter: "showlink", formatoptions: {
    onClick: function (options) {
        // this is DOM of the grid
        // options.iCol is the column index
        // options.iRow is the row index
        // options.rowid is the rowid
        // options.cm is the element from colModel
        // options.cmName is the column name
        // options.cellValue is the text from the <a>
        // options.a - DOM element of the clicked <a>
        // options.event - Event object of the click event
        alert("it's clicked!");
    }
}
```

If you have to use an old version of jqGrid and can't migrate to free jqGrid then you can download `jQuery.jqGrid.dynamicLink.js` from [here](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid-plugins) and to use `formatter: "dynamicLink"`, which I described in [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9048483/315935). See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29456558/315935) too.

If you would do prefer to use your custom formatter, then you can use `beforeSelectRow` callback to implement `onClick` action. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14537512/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13765086/315935) for more details.

Comment: @BellaWesley: The value of `onClick` should be callback function.

Comment: By using the dynamic link formatter like: formatter: "dynamicLink", "formatoptions":{"onClick":$( "#contents" ).load("jsp/consumers.jsp")}, I am  being taken to the page automatically and not "on click." I also tried what you have in the example code as:    formatter: "showlink", formatoptions: {onClick: function (options) {$( "#contents" ).load("jsp/consumers.jsp")} }, but this does not take me to the specified link. It takes me to "origincal url + ?id=XXX"

Comment: @BellaWesley: Could you provide the demo which not works? What is your current problem? Is `onClick` callback will be called? You wrote "this does not take me to the specified link". What behavior you want to have? If you specify `onClick` callback then the `href` will be ignored. You can add `idName: null` inside of `formatoptions` to have `<a href="#">...</a>`. If `onClick` callback will be called then you can assign `location` to any value. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-showlink.htm) as an example which goes to google.