# How do I send a parameter on click to be used in sql query?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, jquery-ui, jqgrid

My UI is a jquery grid. How can I send a parameter to the function (that creates my query) **on click** from my UI jquery grid?

For example, if this was my grid: 
http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-showlink.htm#

I would want the client name sent to the query to use as a filter.
The next page (not google link, as shown in the example when a client is clicked on) would have a grid that only listed companies with that client.

How do I create a query with this functionality?

I want to know how to send a parameter from my UI to the back-end query function.

EDIT ****

Here's what I came up with -

Inside of the UI code (that creates the jqgrid):

```
function returnHyperLink(cellValue, options, rowdata, action)
{
    return '<a id="myLink" href="#" onclick="callCompanies(\''+cellValue+'\');">'+cellValue+'</a>'
}

function callCompanies(cellValue) {
        $("#contents").load("jsp/companies.jsp");

}
```

and then in the back-end code:

I add

```
@GET
@Path("/{cellValue}")
```

to the top of my function and eventually can use cellValue to filter the query, like:

```
+ " where a.evt_type_id = cellValue " + "and "
```

Comment: just append the id/name of client to a back end url/ endpoint like this : http://domain?name=client-name

Comment: If the data isn't private them I would just add it to the url like the comment above. However, if it is private or you want a cleaner operation then I would make an  [ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp) call and send the data with it.

Comment: @binariedMe okay I made an edit to the post. Is that what you are suggesting to do?

Comment: @GaryJohnson This is my first time doing sql. but does the edit to my post look like we are on the same track?

Answer (score 0):

I posted [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-showlink.htm#) for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37700141/315935) on your previous question and described the properties of `options` parameter. The `rowid` is the rowid. Thus one can use `getLocalRow` (`getRowData` or `getCell`) to access to the data from the row. Then one can just append the

```
onClick: function (options) {
    var item = $(this).jqGrid("getLocalRow", options.rowid);
    window.location = "https://www.google.com/#q=" + encodeURIComponent(item.name);
}
```

You can see the results on [the modified demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-showlink1.htm). I remind that `onClick` can be defined in `formatoptions` of `formatter: 'showlink'` for [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork, which I develop.

If you prefer to use custom formatter then you can define the value of `onclick` using `this` and `event`. You can modify the code fragment `onclick="callCompanies(\''+cellValue+'\');"` used in your code to for example following

```
onclick="callCompanies.call(this, \''+cellValue+'\', event);"
```

Then you can use `$(this).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id")` inside of `callCompanies` function to get the rowid. It allows to use `getLocalRow`, `getRowData` or `getCell` to get the data from the row.

Comment: Thank you! I already have the link working just fine; what I'm really wondering about is sql. Do you know how I can transfer that variable, item.name in this example, to my sql code? Would I use a path to carry the parameter over? (as shown above) and can I use the parameter to filter the way I have attempted?

Comment: @JulesMena: JavaScript can't execute an SQL statement directly, but one can send the *parameter* to the server. In the example `q` parameter be used by `google.com` for searching. If you click on the link from [the modified demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-showlink1.htm) then the Google displays the results based on the content of `name` column of the grid. Google makes request to the database internally (it can be compared with SELECT using WHERE) and displays the filtered results.

Comment: In the code that is under my edit, I am trying to send the parameter to the server. By using @Path("/{cellValue}") am I able to use cellValue as a variable in my back-end code? Is this one way I can successfully transfer the parameter and use it in the query statement (using SELECT and WHERE). Like this: Query query = entityManager.createQuery(" Select esd FROM EventSubscriptionDetailEntity esd, " + "  ClientSystemEventConsumerEntity cs, " + **"  WHERE a.evt_type_name = cellValue "** + ......etc

Comment: @JulesMena: Sorry, but the question has no relation to jqGrid. It's only the problem of the backend (server), which you use. I personally use ASP.NET on the server side and getting of any URL parameter is really simple. `@GET` and `@Path` shows that you use some *another* framework on the server side. You should just examine how to get parameters on the server side. It should be very simple (like `@PathParam("paramame")`), but I can't help you here because I use another framework on the server side.

Comment: okay thanks! As far as the grid goes, I just included that as additional background info for a better understanding of what I was doing. I was hoping that by tagging jqgrid, someone would find the question who has done something similar in all aspects of the question.